# Create a usercontrol instance programmatically in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a UserControl that I need to add dynamically. I tried to follow this MSDN article, but I'm not having any success....
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx

The UserControl is basically an image gallery, and it loads some pictures based on an ID. My idea was to make this ID available as a property. Then when I create an instance of the control, I could set this ID and add it to the form.

I added a reference to the control in the .aspx page that will use it, like this:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/PictureGallery.ascx" %>
```

And in the UserControl I added a ClassName like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PictureGallery.ascx.cs"
Inherits="PictureGallery" ClassName="PictureGallery" %>
```

When I try to create an instance in the .aspx.cs like the article suggests, `Dim gallery As ASP.PictureGallery`, I get an "Type ASP.PictureGallery is not defined".

The article mentions a namespace, `ASP`, and I tried importing it to the .aspx.cs with no luck. 
So, I'm not able to get a reference to the UserControl.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are confusing two separate ways of working with a UserControl.

One way is to register the control on your page so that you can put it into the page at Design Time e.g.

```
<div>
    <asp:PictureGallery id="myGallery" runat="server" MyProperty="SomeValue">  
    </asp:PictureGallery>
</div>
```

The second is programmatically (or dynamically) adding it into the page at runtime in your code behind. If so, then you need to use the LoadControl function which is mentioned in the sample. You do not need to register the control in the aspx file if you do this.
e.g.

```
Dim gallery as PictureGallery = LoadControl("~/PathToControl/gallery.ascx")
gallery.MyProperty = "SomeValue"
placeHolder.controls.add(gallery)
```

**edit**
What is the class name of the control in the code behind...something like this:

```
Partial Public Class MyControlsClassName
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

That is the type you need to use when you declare it. Is it within a namespace perhaps?

Comment: Yup, I know this. But doing as you suggest, I get "Type PictureGallery is not defined", and I can't access gallery.MyProperty, not with intellisense anyway. This usually tells me that something is wrong.

Comment: @Soeren, see my edit...its easier to put code in the answer than comment

Comment: Apparently I don't have edit privileges, so I have to put the code here. The classname is 'public partial class PictureGallery : System.Web.UI.UserControl' No namespace...

Comment: @Soeren Is your project C# or VB.net? Your files indicate c#, but you say that Dim etc doesn't work which is vb.net code...so you want me to change my question to be c#?

Comment: The usercontrol is C#, and the page that uses it, is a VB page. So the code I need to instantiate the control is VB..

Comment: and is this in the same project? (it must be a website project, not a web app yeah?)

Comment: I got a chance to test properly on my production server last night, and it turns out that the LoadControl solution works. I just didn't think so, because I got the "Not defined" error and intellisense didn't recognize the property. Of course, the Control is loaded at runtime, and the property is then made available. I'm marking this as my accepted answer. Thanx "davidsleeps" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you've placed the control in your code behind.  You may well have created the reference, but do you have a tag such as `<asp:PictureGalary id="gallary"></asp:PictureGalary>` anywhere in your aspx?

Comment: This is because I add the UserControl programmatically by referencing the ClassName using <%@ Reference Control="~/PictureGallery.ascx" %>.

Comment: What you suggest is adding the UserControl declaratively, and then I would need to register it instead

Answer (score 0):

The ASP namespace is generated at run time- user controls get "compiled" as they are used by .aspx pages so this is why you get the error message "Type ASP.PictureGallery is not defined".

When adding user controls dynamically you should use the P[age.LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) method:

```
Page.LoadControl("~/PictureGallery.ascx")
```