# How we dynamically load the user control at run time on the aspx page

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a usercontrol instance programmatically in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016100/create-a-usercontrol-instance-programmatically-in-asp-net)

Dear Friend 
i have the user control and i what to load the user control on the click of the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create the panel or anything server control

```
<asp:Panel ID="plnExam" runat="server">
 </asp:Panel>
```

then after on cs page

```
Control uc = this.LoadControl("~/UserControl/CollegesInExam.ascx");

plnExam.Controls.Add(uc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://aspalliance.com/565_Dynamic_Loading_of_ASPNET_User_Controls).  (The google phrase you're looking for is "dynamically loading user control")

The key part is 
`Control FeaturedProductUserControl = LoadControl("YourControl.ascx")`

Answer (score 0):

This is in case you will want to load the UserControls via Ajax. Maybe that can be useful:

```
    public static string GetControlHtml(string controlLocation)
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)page.LoadControl(controlLocation);

        //Disabled ViewState- If required
        //userControl.EnableViewState = false;

        HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
        form.Controls.Add(userControl);
        page.Controls.Add(form);
        StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, textWriter, false);
        return CleanHtml(textWriter.ToString());
    }
```

The `controlLocation` is the path from the UserControl (e.g. "~/UserControls/NewUser.ascx").
This method renders the UserControl and returns its HTML ready to be loaded into a contaner (div) via Ajax.